# How to pre-populate the sms body text via an html link on a Windows Phone

Tags: html, windows-phone, sms, nokia

I have been reading around and links indicate that
`sms:?body=test body message` should work but it doesn't seem to work on a Windows Nokia Lumia phone. While this code works on an android phone.

BTW, `sms:;body=test body message` works on iphone.

Any pointers?

Comment: have you tried sms://

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, only thing is there is no associated apps that recognise these types of links but found this that may help
https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/nfcsms/55e57a87-d1fd-420a-8f3c-892c0b7da8af - this APP does work;-) but the user must have the app installed on their phone ;-(

I am adding a prompt or popup so user can either download app and send via sms or  use an emailto  alternative. That should be problem solved.  Hope that helps.